# How to close mat-dialog by pressing Escape Key in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 15.0. I want to close mat-dialog in two ways. the first way is by pressing one of two buttons (submit / cancel) defined in the actions section of dialog, and the other way by pressing Escape key to cancel the operation. in other word, the cancel button and escape key do the same thing.
the parent snippet to open dialog is:

```js
const myDialog = this.operationDialog.open(DialogComponent,
      {
        disableClose: true,          
      });
myDialog.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result !== 'cancel')
        // do somethings
      else
      // operation is canceled
    );
```

the mat-dialog snippet is:

```html
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  ....
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
  <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

And its typescript snippet is:

```js
submit(){  
    this.dialogRef.close(myData);
  }
  
cancel(){   
    this.dialogRef.close('cancel');
 }
```

Is it possible to close the dialog by pressing Escape key so that the result is the same as pressing the cancel button? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: by defect material-angular not close use the ESC or ENTER????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet I think it's possible when you listen to keystrokes and then react on the `Escape`-key.

The following code needs to be placed in your **Dialog TS**:

```
private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listenToEscapeKey();
}

listenToEscapeKey() {
    fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
        // React only to key-events of type 'Escape'
        filter((event: KeyboardEvent) => event.code === 'Escape'),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.cancel();
    });
}

cancel(){   
    this.dialogRef.close('cancel');
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a special cancel logic by subscribing to the `beforeClosed` or `afterClosed` Observable. You also have to enable the Escape key by removing the `disableClose: true` configuration.

```
constructor(...) {
  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('the escape key was hit or the close method was called');
  });
}

cancel() {
  this.dialogRef.close('cancel');
}
```

See also: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogRef